# Joomdle (Joomla & Moodle) administration login

Tags: php, joomla, joomdle

I am working on a Joomla 2.5 application connected to Moodle system via Joomdle plugin. Logging into Joomla via Moodle works fine, but not into administration control panel (ACP). I just can't login into the administration panel because Moodle credentials do not fit to Joomla credentials.

How is it possible to make Joomdle log user in also into ACP while logging into the application? (So he gets logged in to the frontend and backend in once). Not very safe, I know, but it's my clients request.

Is it possible to do this by editing the login script? Or is there some easier way?

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Actually it is a programming question. I am expecting I'll have to change some code. I just don't know how. But I'll create non-programming question there too.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered on Joomla StackExchange:
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/joomdle-2-5-backend-login

It is necesary to write custom authentication plugin. It's pretty easy and with some modifications of ACP login page, the result is exact as I needed.